# NetLogo Custom Patch Mesh

Tags: netlogo

For my model, I need the patch grid in Netlogo to correspond (in shape, size, location) to the mesh in a finite element model. Is there a way to introduce a patch grid that has each patch defined by its coordinate nodes? From the finite element model I can get a matrix defining all the nodes of the elements ( defining mesh geometry ). Any help in translating this to a custom patch grid in Netlogo is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, patches can't be customized in this way. However, you can use turtles to create custom meshes. In the models library, see "Lattice-Walking Turtles Example" under "Code Examples" demonstrates using turtles to create a custom lattice (in this case, hexagonal) and having other turtles move around on that lattice. It sounds like your mesh will be non-homogeneous. In that case, you may want to arrange turtles to form the mesh, and then connect neighbors with links. This will make neighbor checks easier.